# Determining peak to peak voltage of an NE5532 using an 8 ohm speaker

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

In order to calculate the peak to peak voltage of a an op amp (in this case an [NE5532](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5532.pdf)) I need to simply multiply the short circuit current from the data sheet (38ma for this IC in typical operating conditions) and the resistance of the speaker I am using (8ohms). Is this correct?

.038 x 8 = ~600mv

What I am seeing on the oscilloscope seems to tell me this is right as the speaker seems to distort when it starts going much higher than that.

Is there anything in the equitation that I am missing? What part do the supply voltage play in it? I am using -12 / +12.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using an 8-ohm load and expect anything realistically sensible from this and most other op-amps. It's not a power-amp it's an op-amp!! See below: -

[image]

What you see above is the front sheet of the data sheet where they try and say all the nice things they can about the device - note the bit in the red box - if it were better than this they'd have said so.

Comment: TO be honest I don't know what you mean. I tried googling "Output Drive Capability" and "Drive capability" and didn't really find anything that seemed to explain what that information would mean to me? I know the basics of calculating gain and how to figure out filters but I haven't ever seen anything that references this before. Can someone either explain this or point in the direction of a good explanation?

Comment: @Kenn It means that the op-amp can deliver a signal of 10 V\$_{RMS}\$ (28.3V peak to peak sinewave) into a load resistor of 600 ohms.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to drive speakers with NE5532s, then you should take a look at this [Elektor project](http://www.elektor.com/magazines/2010/october/the-5532-opamplifier-part-1.1529745.lynkx).

They use 32 chips per channel to produce 16W of power at 0.1% distortion. The article addresses many of the issues associated with doing this.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: How much hand-holding do I need to do? Both the date of the issue and the title of the article are readily found in the link itself: October 2010, "The 5532 OpAmplifier, Part 1". Most browsers display this information at the bottom when you hover your cursor over the link.

Answer (score 0):

You should not expect the op amp to be able to function in a linear fashion while outputting short circuit current.  This is more of an "absolute maximum" rating of sorts.  You can short circuit the output indefinitely and expect the chip to survive without harm, but you shouldn't expect "normal" functionality during that condition.  In fact, the IC goes out of its way to protect the output from short circuits, and that's why shorts don't kill the chip.

Further, you took the "typical" value for output short circuit current.  Best to design to worst case, which is 10 mA!!!

The data sheet provides Vopp of about 24 volts, which is your maximum output swing for Vcc=+/-15V.  For your 24V Vcc range, I'd guess that the max output swing would be closer to 18V.  To calculate your usable peak voltage in a more friendly way, you look at your maximum input swing, multiply by the gain of your circuit, and make sure the answer you get agrees with things like your max output voltage and slew rate.  If it doesn't, lower your gain or shrink your input.